# Share site pages in sharepoint to organization members

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm searching how to share a unique page site to organization members. The problem is when I share page, users don't see pictures/screenshots in page site. But they can see the content of page site.

I want to know how to share page site with image to organization members.

Answer (score 0):

By design, if users don't permission for pictures, they can not see pictures in the shared page.

As a workaround, you could store these pictures in one picture library, grant picture library with read permission for users. Then share unique page for them.